# How do I rename a database in influxdb?

Tags: r, database, influxdb

1. Looking through the influxdb website, documentation doesn't seem to
   cover some functionality that typical db commands would.  Does
   anyone know how to move to a new name or outright rename a database inside of
   influxdb?
2. Does anyone have a recommendation which R package to use with
   influxdb?
3. Is there a way to load influx with `-precision rfc3339` (human
   readable timestamping) automatically set within the configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently **renaming** databases is **not supported** in influxDB. Discussion is going on in influxDB's github repo on the feature's need and complexity.

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4154

The feature was implemented and then reverted due to bugs

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming is only possible by copying data into a new database:

```
SELECT * INTO "copy_NOAA_water_database"."autogen".:MEASUREMENT FROM "NOAA_water_database"."autogen"./.*/ GROUP BY *
```

Documentation: https://archive.docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2//query_language/data_exploration/#example-1-rename-a-database

The `GROUP BY *` clause is important as it preserves the tags.

Answer (score -3):

I have not tried it for myself. But there are some answers in this link https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb.com/issues/384

```
ALTER DATABASE <db> RENAME TO <new_db>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: This feature was never introduced